# Syntax for linking to multiple related records

Tags: sql

I can't get the syntax to work for this SQL query.

I have a database with [many more than] 3 tables:

TUnit contains fields

- UnitUnit
- UnitPrevUnit
- UnitNextUnit

TBatch contains fields¨

- BatUnit
- BatBatch

TProcess contains fields

- ProcBatch
- ProcStartTime
- ProcEndTime

I'm trying to get SQL to return these fields, for each record from TUnit:

- UnitUnit
- the ProcStartTime related to ProcBatch = BatBatch where BatUnit = UnitNextUnit
- the ProcEndTime related to ProcBatch = BatBatch where BatUnit = UnitNextUnit
- the ProcStartTime related to ProcBatch = BatBatch where BatUnit = UnitLastUnit
- the ProcEndTime related to ProcBatch = BatBatch where BatUnit = UnitLastUnit

I can show

- UnitUnit
- ProcStartTime and ProcEndTime for one of either UnitNextUnit or UnitLastUnit (but not both)

with the following (working) code

```
SELECT 
TUNIT.UNITUNIT,
TUNIT.UNITNEXTUNIT,
TBATCH.BATUNIT,
TBATCH.BATBATCH,
TPROCESS.PROCENDTIME,
TPROCESS.PROCSTARTTIME  from TPROCESS
   inner join TBATCH on TBATCH.BATBATCH=TPROCESS.PROCBATCH
   inner join TUNIT on TUNIT.UNITNEXTUNIT=TBATCH.BATUNIT
   where TBATCH.BATTYPE=100
```

I try to add the other ProcStartTime as follows, and fail with error message "Incorrect syntax near ','." :

```
SELECT 
TUNIT.UNITUNIT,
TUNIT.UNITNEXTUNIT,
TBATCH.BATUNIT,
TBATCH.BATBATCH,
TPROCESS.PROCENDTIME,
TPROCESS.PROCSTARTTIME  from TPROCESS
   inner join TBATCH on TBATCH.BATBATCH=TPROCESS.PROCBATCH
   inner join TUNIT on TUNIT.UNITNEXTUNIT=TBATCH.BATUNIT
   where TBATCH.BATTYPE=100,

TPROCESS.PROCSTARTTIME  from TPROCESS
   inner join TBATCH on TBATCH.BATBATCH=TPROCESS.PROCBATCH
   inner join TUNIT on TUNIT.UNITPREVUNIT=TBATCH.BATUNIT
   where TBATCH.BATTYPE=100
```

Help me out here? How do I get those two joins into the same statement?

Sorry, I'm obviously a database newbee, so I don't know the proper language for expressing my problem...

Comment: Isn't your first query already have `PROCSTARTTIME`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write your `JOIN` starting with `TUNIT`, and `JOIN`ing `TBATCH` and `TPROCESS` twice to get the start times for each unit:

```
SELECT 
    TUNIT.UNITUNIT,
    TUNIT.UNITNEXTUNIT,
    TB1.BATUNIT AS NEXTUNIT,
    TB1.BATBATCH AS NEXTBATCH,
    TP1.PROCENDTIME AS NEXTENDTIME,
    TP1.PROCSTARTTIME AS NEXTSTARTTIME,
    TUNIT.UNITPREVUNIT,
    TB2.BATUNIT AS PREVUNIT,
    TB2.BATBATCH AS PREVBATCH,
    TP2.PROCENDTIME AS PREVENDTIME,
    TP2.PROCSTARTTIME AS PREVSTARTTIME
FROM TUNIT
INNER JOIN TBATCH TB1 on TUNIT.UNITNEXTUNIT=TB1.BATUNIT
INNER JOIN TPROCESS TP1 on TB1.BATBATCH=TP1.PROCBATCH
INNER JOIN TBATCH TB2 on TUNIT.UNITPREVUNIT=TB2.BATUNIT
INNER JOIN TPROCESS TP2 on TB2.BATBATCH=TP2.PROCBATCH
WHERE TB1.BATTYPE=100 AND TB2.BATTYPE = 100
```

Comment: Thank you for the pedagogical answer! It worked right away.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a Union.

```
 select unitunit, TProcess.ProcStartTime, TProcess.ProcEndTime from TUnit
    inner join TBatch on TBatch.BatBatch = TUnit.UnitNextUnit
    inner join TProcess on TProcess.ProcBatch = TBatch.BatBatch
    union 
    select unitunit, TProcess.ProcStartTime, TProcess.ProcEndTime from TUnit
    inner join TBatch on TBatch.BatBatch = TUnit.UnitLastUnit
    inner join TProcess on TProcess.ProcBatch = TBatch.BatBatch
```

You may have to add aliases to make the columns more readable.